# Add Controls in MVVM way but don't declare control type straight

Tags: c#, wpf

Point-black question.

Is it possible to add/generate controls in MVVM way without control type declaration in XAML code ? Well it's hard to put that in a words so let's take an example:

There is `Controls` table in SQL Server, which has columns like this:

 `1. ControlName
 2. ControlType
 3. ControlBinding (?)`

Now, in my `ViewModel` I'm declaring an `ObservableCollection<T>` which would be collection of those controls I would like to have, and populating it from `Controls` table. By binding to `ItemsSource` of course.

As far as I know it's simple to add controls dynamically, but only when we declare type straight e.g :

```
<StackPanel>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SomeCollection}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=.}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

Is there any way to do same thing, but taking control type from database ?

Comment: Does the VM have to be generated?

Comment: When there is a fixed set of DataTemplates for different collection item types, declare DataTemplates as resources and set their DataType property. To be even more dynamic, write a DataTemplateSelector and assign it to the ItemsControl's ItemTemplateSelector property.

Comment: @MickyD What do you mean ? Generate VM other than main ViewModel ?

Comment: By that I mean if your intent is to define all controls in the DB, thus eliminating changes to the V, then how do you do your binding?  I can think of a way but only if I code-gen the entire V and VM

Comment: @Clemens DataTemplateSelector is great idea, but I don't know how would it be dynamic. How DTS would know how much controls do I need ? As far as i know DataTemplate are created in XAML, not in code-behind. Am I right ?

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you mean with "dynamic". Even a DataTemplateSelector would usually operate with a set of predefined (in XAML) DataTemplates. If you want to *generate* the view elements, you don't need a DataTemplate.

Comment: @Clemens Well I'm consufed right now. Let's say there are 2 records in my Controls table: one for TextBox and one for ComboBox. Does it mean I have to create one DataTemplate with TextBox and one DataTemplate with ComboBox ? Then I'm adding those DataTemplates to ObservableCollection ? Well, I must say, I have to find greate example.

Comment: You do of course not add DataTemplates to the ItemsSource collection. Take a look at [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview) first.

Comment: Assuming you have TextData and ComboBoxData types that are supposed to be used with TextBox and ComboBox respectively, you would declare two DataTemplate resources with e.g. `DataType="{x:Type local:TextData}"` and `DataType="{x:Type local:ComboBoxData}"`. These DataTemplates would be used *automatically* for each TextData or CombBoxData in the ItemsSource collections.

Comment: @Clemens I see the light at the end of a tunnel. Thank you for your tips.

Comment: What made you store the information about the controls in the database? In the database one would only store data. When retrieving that data one would put them in a model class of some sorts, then that data is evaluated by the `ItemsControl` which in turn uses `DataTemplates` with `TargetTypes`. This approach leaves you to manually resolve the controls while if you retrieve that information in a proper model class it would have been done automatically.

Comment: @XAMINAX This app requires to be automatized, because of users who will be using it. They should have possibility to customize controls by adding or deleting it. At the moment I have no idea how to finalized it without storing informations in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to create `DataTemplates` and implement `DataTemplateSelector`.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TextBoxDataTemplate">
        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="200" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding ControlName}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            <TextBox VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="205,0,0,0" Width="616" Height="35" FontSize="12" Text="{Binding ControlValue,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxDataTemplate">
        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="200" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding ControlName}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            <ComboBox VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="205,0,0,0" Width="616" Height="35" FontSize="15"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

And `ControlTemplateSelector`

```
 public class ControlTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var element = container as FrameworkElement;
        var control = item as ControlModel;

        if (element != null & control != null)
        {
            if (control.ControlType.Equals("TextBox"))
            {
                return element.FindResource("TextBoxDataTemplate") as DataTemplate;
            }
            else
            {
                return element.FindResource("ComboBoxDatatemplate") as DataTemplate;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Then I just bound `ItemsSource` and `ItemTemplateSelector` in my `ItemsControl` just like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ControlsCollection}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ControlTemplateSelector}"/>
```

`ControlsCollection` is populated from database.